# Feature detecting support for svg filters

Tags: browser, svg, gaussian, svg-filters, browser-feature-detection

I need to feature detect whether a browser supports svg filters (feGaussianBlur, to be specific). How would I go about testing for this? Safari, which doesn't support the filter, silently ignores the filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably also check the enums available on the interfaces, e.g:

```
var supportsfilter = typeof SVGFEColorMatrixElement !== undefined && 
                     SVGFEColorMatrixElement.SVG_FECOLORMATRIX_TYPE_SATURATE==2;
```

That way you won't have to construct new elements, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767059/109374. I've not tested to see whether this works as expected in Safari.

**Update:**
Patch submitted to modernizr: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/531

Comment: I was initially looking for something like this in the DOM tree in firebug but couldn't find anything. What are these interfaces? - global variables that aren't added to the window object? *edit* I now see them - I had to set firebug to show non-enumerable properties

Comment: A bit of extra weirdness though - the properties don't show up in the DOM (aren't initialised?) until after an SVG is added to the page or `SVGFEColorMatrixElement` is called in the console. I've tested in safari and a reference error is thrown, as you might expect, so the test would need a try/catch block. +1

Comment: These are just constants that should be there always, if the browser implements the corresponding DOM interface. How about the variant that uses typeof?

Comment: @ErikDahlström, i was trying to slove this problem using console.log(document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Filter", "1.1")) inside the svg document, but unfortunately returns false in both Firefox and safari. Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yxVSe/ which examines the existence of the properties of GaussianBlur.
Say GaussianBlur has a method `setStdDeviation`, we check for the existence of that method, when fails we come to a conclusion that the current browser dosent support that filter.

When this fiddle is check in safari texts would be in red, while in firefox it will be green.

Comment: The `if(filterTag.constructor.toString().indexOf('SVGFilterElement') != -1)` test is not correctly detecting Opera (which supports svg filters).

Comment: @Erik Dahlstrom - good spot, although playing around a bit it looks like that line of code was unnecessary anyway. I've whittled the test down to just 3 lines, which give the desired results across browsers `var blur = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feGaussianBlur");
  blur.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "2");
  return (typeof blur.setStdDeviation !== 'undefined' );`

Comment: In fact, the second line of that isn't needed either, so a 2 line test will do fine.

Comment: in case anyone comes here after 10+ years: Safari is shit and doesn't implement this method - despite the standard svg spec - but you can still set it on the elements with .setAttribute('stdDeviation', '5')

Answer (score 0):

I added a small modification for legacy Androids bug

```
var supportsfilter = window['SVGFEColorMatrixElement'] !== undefined && SVGFEColorMatrixElement.SVG_FECOLORMATRIX_TYPE_SATURATE == 2
```