# How to hide an SVG picture if the browser doesn't support filters

Tags: svg, cross-browser, svg-filters

I am currently working with the SVG format in a website. I'd like to create awesome blurs, it' works fine but some browsers don't like SVG filters, so the blur is not displayed. Instead only the "not blurred" shape is displayed. For this reason I'd like to hide the whole SVG picture if the browser partially supports SVG. The question is: how can be done in an elegant way? Is there any non-JavaScript solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739955/feature-detecting-support-for-svg-filters I can't imagine a way to do this without JS.

Comment: Yes, you can do this without JS in an elegant way. You set a filter on a transparent <rect> element and use an feImage primitive to pull in the contents that you would like to blur. Only browsers that support filters will display the content, and browsers that do not support this will not.